# How check the file extension zend validator?

Tags: zend-framework, validation

I need to upload the file to the database and check it out before the expansion of the validator.
Do so - take the content of a file function *file_get_contents* and file name from the *$ _FILES*.
Need to check the file extension (zend validator). How?

What wrong in my code:

```
        $allowed_ext = 'pic, jpg, gif, png, bmp';
        $validator = new Zend_Validate_File_Extension();
        return $validator->isValid($allowed_ext, $fileName);
        if (!$validator->isValid($allowed_ext, $file)) 
            return 'Invalid extension';
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
$validator = new Zend_Validate_File_Extension();
$validator->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg,jpeg,png,gif');
```

Comment: hello , i am trying like this `$validator->addValidator('Extension', false, 'tar.gz');` but its not working , can u please tell me why